# Check if any modal is opened by their id and then close that modal IONIC

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3, ionic4

I have many modals open in my app and I want to close some specific modals only so first I want to check if that modal is open by checking with their modal id and then close that modal .

```
const modal = await this.modalCtrl.create({
   component: AddPayeeConfirmPage,
   cssClass: 'modal-form',
   backdropDismiss: false,
   id:"AddPayeeConfirmPage",
   componentProps: { 'fromAccountNumber': this.addPayeeForm.value.from_account_number,'beneficiaryDetail': beneficiary,'amount': this.addPayeeForm.value.amount,'description':this.addPayeeForm.value.description,'currencyType':this.currencyType }
});
```